# Unknown triangle symbol in single line diagram

Tags: symbol, diagram

I have some troubles finding what the triangle symbol on the following diagram could mean.
[image: Diagram of the cabinet]
It is not a diode because in other parts of the diagram, it is used where an input is expected.

The box is an electrical cabinet that contains circuit-breakers. The top one is an input and the 4 bottom one are outputs.

I guess it could mean that the ground cable is linked to the cabinet casing but I couldn't find any confirmation on that online and it seems strange.

Comment: The lines, across he main line, show amount of conductors. So, triangle may be some kind of terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single line diagram, such triangles or arrow heads represent outgoing feeders.

Here are some more examples.

[image]   [image]

[image]